# How to springboot Logback Prevent deleting of older Log files

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

My spring-boot application keeps archive logs for only 7 days as defined in the defaults as defined in the [logging defaults](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core).

The issue is that I need these logs to always be there and never be deleted.

Is there a way to specify this?

sample Config

```
logging:
  file:
    name: logs/application.log
  file.max-size: 200MB
  level:
    org.apache.http: INFO
    org.springframework.cloud.sleuth: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
```

Comment: How about setting logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history to 999999999 days?

Comment: You need to put those logs somewhere long-term and not accumulate them in the place your application is running.

Comment: @ewramner yes this will work in holding but I was thinking of a more standard solution

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- you are correct, the company policy is to backup and not let them accumulate on the server, I can do as ewramner suggested and use a ridiculous number but as I said before, I am looking for the standard solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*According to the logback documentation*, [setting maxHistory to zero disables archive removal](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpMaxHistory) and [setting totalSizeCap to zero disables archive removal by combined size threshold.](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpTotalSizeCap) However, it is mentioned that "*The totalSizeCap property requires maxHistory property to be set as well*". [The maxHistory of default FileAppender in Spring Boot is 7 by default.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history)
*So, setting*

> logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=0

*in your application properties might do the trick.*

```yaml
logging:
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-file-size: 0
  file:
    name: logs/application.log
    max-size: 200MB
  level:
    org:
      apache:
        http: INFO
      springframework:
        cloud:
          sleuth: INFO
        web: INFO
```